# java simple calculator but no result

Tags: java, calculator

yeah i tried to make a really simple calculator myself in java. but it cannot make print the math out i type. it has no error i tried to search the mistake but cant find a solution.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Øvelse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String calculator;

        System.out.print("skriv nummer: ");
        int num1 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("skriv nummer: ");
        int num2 = in.nextInt();

        Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("skriv + - * /: ");
        calculator = op.nextLine();

        if(calculator == "+") {
            System.out.println("resultat1 " + num1 + num2);
        }

        if(calculator == "-") {
            System.out.println("resultat3 ");
        }

        if(calculator == "/") {
            System.out.println("resultat3 " + num1 / num2);
        }

        if(calculator == "*") {
            System.out.println("resultat4 " + num1 * num2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's partly a dupe of the compare strings question, and partly of the nextFoo question.

Comment: fozzi - Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832).  They describe the two things you're doing wrong.

Comment: if(calculator.equals("+"){
Use .equals not ==
Also use if and else if statements or better yet, a switch statement.

Comment: There are two issues, 1) he's using integer comparison instead of string and 2) he's appending numbers rather than doing math, see my answer below.

Comment: Tip: [Use a debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @JordanGS Three issues.  See my earlier comment for the other one.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the scanner isn't skipping anything so there's no scanner issue.

Comment: I disagree completely.  Try it.  You'll see.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem i don't care if you disagree, there's no reason for the scanner to miss anything. There's nothing wrong with the code, but i did humor you and tried it out. The scanner doesn't have any issues. It takes 2 numbers and an operator. Maybe you need to try it yourself? Maybe it was an issue in JDK6 or early versions of JDK7, don't know. I'm running JDK 8 and the scanner works fine. Try it yourself if you don't believe me,

Answer (score 0):

Couple issues

1) When doing string compare. You can't use `==`, to use string comparison then you should as an example. `calculator.equals("+")`. The `intA == intB` is when comparing integers, `varA.equals(varB)` is when you compare strings.

2) You can do math like that

`System.out.println("resultat1 " + num1 + num2);` will just append text, you have to isolate the math with brackets `(..)`, such as

`System.out.println("resultat1 " + (num1 + num2));`, this will now do addition.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to compare Strings you needa use `equals` not the `==` operator (in your case you should even use a `switch` statement rather than multiple `if` statements).

Secondly `"abc"+3+4` is different from `"abc"+(3+4)`.